# Running flask app with socket-io and it is stopping after debug statement

Tags: sockets, flask, websocket

I am trying to run this app.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host="http://some.link.xyz", port=5500)
```

And this is where it gets stuck:
[image]

How do I resolve it? I get nothing on `some.link.xyz:5500`

I was expecting it to run on port 5500.

Answer (score 0):

So, turned out it was due to eventlet:
Replace:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

with:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=False, socket=True)
```